# Can I overload an operator in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, operator-overloading

Is it possible to override operator use in Objective-C?

For example

```
myClassInstance + myClassInstance
```

calls a custom function to add the two.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Operator overloading is not a feature of Objective-C. If two instances of your classes can be added together, provide a method and allow them to be added using that method:

```
Thing *result = [thingOne thingByAddingThing:thingTwo];
```

Or, if your class is mutable:

```
[thingOne addThing:thingTwo];
```

Comment: Concatenating strings is a pain.

Answer (score 16):

No, you can't do this in Objective-C.

Comment: any reason for that?

Answer (score 8):

You can do this now in [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), a successor to objC. And since Objective-C and Swift are made to work together [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID42) could be interesting for you.

Comment: Have a look at the [Swift page](https://developer.apple.com/swift/) on Apple's developer website. It says: Swift is a successor to the C and Objective-C languages.

Comment: Ok. Could you post a concrete example? As I understand swift code may be included into Objective C one.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to support subscripting for your object. Subscripting is *not* operator overloading, but it can be handy for a collection object. NSArray and NSDictionary both support subscripting. For example:

`NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray new]; 
a[0] = @"Hello";`

The way to support index subscripting is to implement the following:

`-(id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;
 -(void)setObject:(id)newObject atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx];`

Comment: Actually, `[]` is considered an operator in both C and C++, so in a sense, `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` is a way to overload an operator.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I just wanted to leave this answer here for anybody in the future that might want to know if this is a possibility.

The answer is YES!

You'll have to use a variant of Objective-C called Objective-C++.
As an example, say you created a new Objective-C command-line tool project. In order to allow C++ functionality, you'll need to rename "main.m" to "main.mm". Afterwards, you can mix C++ code in with your Objective-C code in the same file. There are some limitations, but I've tested operator overloading and it seems to work perfectly fine with Objective-C objects as far as I can tell.
I've included sample source code to give you an idea of how to do it:

```
//main.mm
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, NSString *s) {
    os << [s UTF8String];
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString *str = @"I'm an NSString!";
        std::cout << str << std::endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my output after building and running this code:

> ```
> I'm an NSString!
> Program ended with exit code: 0
> ```

Hopefully this will be of help to somebody!

Comment: When I see Objective C++, I only wonder how the compiler does its job! C, Objective C and C++ altogether!

Answer (score 0):

No, Objective-C does not support operator overloading.

Answer (score -28):

First, operator overloading is **evil**.  Second, C doesn't have operator overloading, and Objective-C is a proper superset of C, which only adds a handful of keywords and a messaging syntax.

That being said, if you're using Apple's development environment, you can use Objective-C++ instead of Objective-C, which gives you access to all of C++'s mistakes and misfeatures, including operator overloading.  The simplest way to use Objective-C++ is just to change the extension on your implementation files from ".m" to ".mm"

Comment: I don't think it's fair to categorically say it's evil. It doesn't generally seem to pose a big problem in Smalltalk, Ruby, Python or Haskell.

Comment: Having worked on several large python projects, operator overloading can very much be evil....  Lost countlessnhours to buggy overloads.  Mostly in trying to find the damned things.

Comment: Smalltalk doesn't have operator overloading, it has binary messages which behave the same as all the other messages.

Comment: If ever you need to recreate basic datatypes. (And I do) loosing operator overloading is crippling
A+B*C-D becomes A.add(B.times(C)).Minus(C))

Comment: there are many genuine use cases for operator overloading and other C++ features. I can write something to e.g. evaluate bezier curves for any type implementing addition and multiplication, with one piece of code - something impossible in Objective-C or C. I like writing one function instead of 16... its very reliable and maintainable

Comment: You've inadvertently given an example of why overloading is evil.  What does it even mean to multiply a bezier curve?

Comment: So let me understand: if I have Vector type (for each game programming language) which I have written, or similar things, you prefer to write myVector.Add(theOtherVector).Cross(somethingElse) instead of (myVector + theOtherVector) * somethingElse? Sorry, btu this answer is completely subjective and definitely not explained.

Comment: A _"proper superset of `C`"_ might very well provide a mechanism for operator overloading (even if Objective C does not).

Comment: @NSResponder The beauty of operator overloading is that `*` doesn't necessarily mean *multiply*, it's just "the star operator" and it can mean whatever you want it to mean (within the confines of how the implementation allows it, bearing in mind operator precedence, etc.). Granted that can lead to confusion and misuse, but at the same time it's incredibly powerful.

Comment: Even in objective c++ you can only use operator overloading in your c++ classes, which still dosn't help you much if your trying to use objective c

Comment: "Operator overloading = evil".. Ignorance at its best.

Comment: You misspelled "experience", Chris.

Comment: Good on you for sticking to your guns with this answer. I tend to agree. I have to agree that in my experience I have seen more abuses of operator overloading than legitimate uses. When I encounter `Path p = "C:" / "Windows" / "System32"; // slash operator allows OS-independence` I instinctively think "Why?!". And yes, I did see that line of code once, comment included.

Comment: This sounds like an answer from someone who has never used C#'s structs.

Comment: Just because something CAN be abused (and may be frequently abused), does NOT make it evil...

Comment: what's wrong with this answer? people must be crazy

Comment: I think it's clear that operator overloading is fine for all monoids, and possibly for many groupoids such as magmas, too.  -1 for a hardline position (which I used to take, too).  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid.  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_%28algebra%29.  Arrays and strings are at least magmas.

Comment: While this could be considered an aggressive answer to the question, the provided stance IS an answer to the question. Frankly, I agree myself with his point of view. Operator overloading gives too much power to the programmer, and with great power comes great responsibility. And unfortunately, this responsibility is oft left half done or half baked. Objective-C messages are fairly easy to manage and while it may be inconvenient to have to write it all out, the final outcome is a more readably understandable line of code.