# Overloaded operators in C via macros with type notification

Tags: c, macros, operator-overloading

The C preprocessor can't be used to overload operators, since it doesn't know the types of a and b in the expression "a+b", see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140071/operator-overloading-equivalent-with-define-in-c-objective-c).

However, what about giving it the type, something like this:

```
out = (a*b+b*n) x c : {a,b,c->vector3, n->float};
```

Which would be preprocessed into:

```
vector3 out = cross(add(dot(a,b), mult(b,n)),c);
```

This work around, useful when migrating the codebase to C++ or interfacing C and C++ is not worth the trouble, is no less verbose. However, the expression left of the : is much easier to read.

Is such a solution feasible?

Comment: This would be preprocessed... by what?

Comment: Some macro that hopefully wouldn't be too hard to write.

Comment: I really really doubt that something like this would be accepted somewhere except experimental/code-obfuscation areas. Think headache to debug such things - overkill

Comment: Targeting a homebrew half-baked macro processor, or targeting a real language like C++? That's a hard dilemma...

Comment: @n.m: Your right that not invented here is a common disease. But C++ brings up portability problems in my case. No, I won't try any fancy metaprogramming, simply using the verbose way is fine. This is more for me to get a feel for the capability of macros.

Comment: "C++ brings up portability problems". Your solution brings **unknown** problems. I'll stick with gcc. You do realize you cannot use standard macros and have to conjure up your own macro processor, right?

Comment: @n.m. Yes that's partly why I won't do it. Just not worth it. The normal way of spelling out "add" and "cross" is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with C preprocessor, and I can simply prove it by simply *listing all the preprocessor directives*.

- `#include` (copy-pastes the content of the file)
- `#define` (macros)
- `#if`, `#else`,`#elif`, `#ifdef`, `#ifndef` (conditional compilation)
- `#line` (changing value of `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`)
- `#error` (enforce a compilation error)
- `#pragma` (compiler-dependent functionality)
- `#` (empty directive, does nothing)

The one functionality you're interested in, macros, only work for identifiers:

```
#define MAX(a,b) replacement
#define VALUE replacement
```

`+`, `*`, `:`, `{`, `}` are not identifiers.