# Overloading the [] operator in Objective-C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, operator-overloading, objective-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I overload an operator in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613980/can-i-overload-an-operator-in-objective-c)

In, objective-C++, is it possible to overload the message passing operator, i.e. the []? Is it possible to the same with "."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on what you want your overloaded message passing to do.

Message passing in Objective C is dynamic and you can insert code into the message passing system at several levels. The easiest is [Message Forwarding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html). Beyond that, there is [Dynamic Method Resolution](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtDynamicResolution.html) and using [`class_replaceMethod()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW66) from the [runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html).

The dot operator for Objective-C properties is a short-cut for message passing. It works just like message passing calling `-prop` and `-setProp:` for getting and setting the property.

The dot operator for C structs is not overloadable.

Answer (score 1):

Operator-overloading in just a feature of C++ not of Objective-C. Look at the Question:
[Can I overload an operator in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613980/can-i-overload-an-operator-in-objective-c)

From my knowledge of C++ (don't know its fully supported in Objective-C++) you can overload the [] operator but not the . operator as you can read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/).

**Edit** (after the input of JefferyThomas ty): Objective-C++ does not support overloading the message passing operator. The answer I gave is correct but doesn't apply that operator (only to array subscripting or other "features" of c++)

Comment: user1107412 wants to overload message passing, not array subscripting.

Comment: @JefferyThomas does that make any difference, what the actual purpose of the operator was? (I don't think so. Please correct me if I am wrong!)

Comment: C++ cannot support `[instance method:parameter]` overloading. It's not a part of C++ syntax. Think of it this way, you would need a method signature of `id operator[](id instance, SEL method, ...)`. It just doesn't exist in C++.

Answer (score 0):

For overloading the c++ subscript operator,

```
class MyClass {
private: 
    int myList[10];
public:
    int& operator [] (const int index) {return myList[index];} // Check for index out of bounds if necessary.
};
```

This is how it normally looks. The int& is for returning the reference, so you can write

```
MyClass a;
a[1] = 3;
```

Without the int&, you can only access, and not modify it. Read more [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/74a-returning-values-by-value-reference-and-address/).

You can not overload operators in Objective-C.
Regarding your question of overloading the ".", there are only a number of operators you can overload, which is:

```
+    -    *    /    =    <    >    +=   -=   *=   /=   <<   >>
<<=  >>=  ==   !=   <=   >=   ++   --   %    &    ^    !    |
~    &=   ^=   |=   &&   ||   %=   []   ()   ,    ->*  ->   new 
delete    new[]     delete[]
```